# How are documents retrieved after reduce produces the output?

Tags: mapreduce, search-engine

So, after reduce completes its job we have data stored in the files something like this:

[image]

But what happens when the user types something? How is search performed when the data is stored just in files?

Comment: Your question is not cleat please elaborate

Answer (score 2):

MapReduce is for processing. So once you have processed the data and generated your aggregate information, which is on HDFS, you will either have to read the file in some program to display to user. Or several alternative options are available to read the data from HDFS :
You could use Hive and create a table on top of this data and read the data using SQL like queries. A simple web application can connect to this using the thrift server which provides a JDBC interface to hive.
Other options include loading data to HBase, Shark etc. All depends on what your use case is interms of the size of the aggregated data, performance requirements

Answer (score 1):

What you have constructed after MapReduce is a inverted index, a nice little data structure. Now you have to use it.

For example, in case of google, this inverted index is sharded across many servers and stores the entire list on each of them. So for example, server 500 has the list for be, and another has the list for to. These are implementation details, you could theoretically store it on one box in a large hash if you could hold the index in memory.

When the customer types in words into the engine. It will retrieve that entire list. If there are multiple words, it will do an intersection of those lists to show you documents that have both words.

Here is the source for the full paper on how they did it http://infolab.stanford.edu/~backrub/google.html

See "Figure 4. Google Query Evaluation"